# Function to organise a table

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I have a table which I would like to make more dynamic based on values in two ranges.

[image: Table]

- I have a first table - DATE - (one column containing 1st January 2021 - 31st December 2022)
- I have a second table - UUID - (one column containing the UUID)

Is there a way to display Each date individually for each UUID there is for each day like in the picture with a single formula?

Thanks alot!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Hello,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OH_LF9r04rRb1ZMuc26CwIq3NQ-qWVlb8mXJwuTechk/edit#gid=1732409545

MODTANEWBIE_PER E3:E is list of UIDs
DST!A3:A is list of days

in ATT_DATABASE I would like to feed it automatically with both DATE in column A and UID from MODTANEWBIE_PER sheet.

Additionaly is there a way to get the respective value form sheet ATT_ARCHIVE based on DATE and UID please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(DST!A4:A, DST!A4:A<>"")&"×"&
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(MODTANEWBIE_PER!E3:E, MODTANEWBIE_PER!E3:E<>""))), "×"))
```

and for count:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4:A&B4:B, 
 {ATT_ARCHIVE!A4:A&ATT_ARCHIVE!B3, ATT_ARCHIVE!B4:B;
  ATT_ARCHIVE!A4:A&ATT_ARCHIVE!C3, ATT_ARCHIVE!C4:C}, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks again for alot of help!

May I please ask you on advice on one last thing?

I created a new view in ATT_FINAL!E9:I13 where I tried to do an arrayformula to get the data  from the database based on DATE and UID one by one separately.

Is it possible to make arrayformula that would be used accross all DATES (Column) and UIDs ( ROW ) ?

Even if it worked accross only DATES or UIDS it would be great!

Thanks again!

Comment: @Mara try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDPWs.png